# How to deserialize JSON to a Swift object?

Tags: json, swift

Is there any way to deserialize JSON to a Swift object, not to `NSDictionay`?

For example: a JSON is like: `{"value": "xxx"}`

I want to use this resource like:

```
var json = "{\"value\": \"xxx\"}"
var obj = parseToObj(json)
println(obj.value)
```

Comment: What is `parseToObj`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a small library to handle things like this swiftly. (No pun intended) You can get it here: [JSONHelper](https://github.com/isair/JSONHelper#json-string-deserialization)

After reading your question I realized that I should add deserialization support directly from JSON strings and not just JSON response objects, so I did.

Here is how you do it:

```
struct MyObjectType: Deserializable {
    var value: String?

    init(data: [String: AnyObject]) {
        value <-- data["value"]
    }
}

var json = "{\"value\": \"xxx\"}"
var myClass: MyClass?

myClass <-- json

println("\(myClass.value)")
```